# Image classification with Independent Component Analysis ICA

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I am developing a system to classify a set of images. I have 700 image for training and 300 images for test. To each one I applied a FastICA process with a initial mixing matrix A. The goal of my system is to compare each image in the test set with each image of the training set and get the nearest image from the training set using the independent components.

My question is how to make this comparison using the independent components. I've tried the Euclidean distance between independent components of each image in the training set and the test set, but it doesn't work.

I am using MATLAB and [FastICA](http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/fastica/) implementation.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"? Can you clarify what you expected to happen and what actually happened?

Comment: I refer that I get less than 10% of effectivity. The Euclidean distance doesn´t work to compare independent components.

Comment: What is your generative/statistical model? in what sense you expect the independent components to be the same?

Comment: @Shai in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469828/dimension-reduction-using-pca-for-fastica/15472680) I explain the goal of my system, can you help me please?