# dimension reduction using pca for FastICA

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pca

I am trying to develop a system for image classification. I am using following the article:

*INDEPENDENT COMPONENT ANALYSIS (ICA) FOR TEXTURE CLASSIFICATION* by Dr. Dia Abu Al Nadi and Ayman M. Mansour

In a paragraph it says:

> Given the above texture images, the Independent Components are learned by the method outlined above.
>   The (8 x 8) ICA basis function for the above textures are shown in Figure 2. respectively. The dimension is reduced by PCA, resulting in a total of 40 functions. Note that independent components from different windows size are different.

The "method outlined above" is FastICA, the textures are taken from [Brodatz album](http://www.ux.uis.no/~tranden/brodatz.html) , each texture image has `640x640` pixels. My question is:

What the authors means with "The dimension is reduced by PCA, resulting in a total of 40 functions.", and how can I get that functions using matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PCA (Principal Component Analysis)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) is a method for finding an orthogonal basis (think of a coordinate system) for a high-dimensional (data) space. The "axes" of the PCA basis are sorted by variance, i.e. along the first PCA "axis" your data has the largest variance, along the second "axis" the second largest variance, etc.

This is exploited for dimension reduction: Say you have 1000 dimensional data. Then you do a PCA, transform your data into the PCA basis and throw away all but the first 20 dimensions (just an example). If your data follows a certain statistical distribution, then chances are that the 20 PCA dimensions describe your data almost as well as the 64 original dimensions did. There are methods for finding the number of dimensions to use, but that is beyond scope here.

Computationally, PCA amounts to finding the Eigen-decomposition of your data's covariance matrix, in Matlab: `[V,D] = eig(cov(MyData))`.

Note that if you want to work with these concepts you should do some serious reading. A classic article on what you can do with PCA on image data is [Turk and Pentland's Eigenfaces](http://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/PCA/jcn.pdf). It also gives some background in an understandable way.

Comment: Thanks for you help. Please, can you tell me why do you mention 64 dimensional data if each texture has 640x640 pixels? sorry if it's a simple question, but I am noob on PCA. The goal of the dimension reduction is later convert each one of the 40 functions on 8x8 matrices, to finally apply FastICA on them.

Comment: If I understand the paper correctly, the authors reduce the number of ICA basis functions using PCA. Sorry, I wrote my answer somewhat misleading regarding my examples for dimension numbers; I changed that now. Each individual ICA basis is of size 8x8 pixels (i.e. 64 values). I guess the number of ICA basis functions is equal the number of textures in the database, and this number is reduced to 40 by PCA.

Comment: Am little confused with the meaning of dimension, I search info about it, and in many articles says than a dimension is each pixel value on a image, in another article a dimension is each row of a image. what is considered a dimension on a image using PCA?

Comment: Dimension is a very general mathematical concept, and what it means is entirely dependent on the algorithm you are working with. In your case I think the "dimension" reduced by PCA is the number of ICA basis functions.

Comment: Please, one more question, if the article says that I have to reduce to 40 functions with PCA, it refers to obtain 40 functions from each texture or only 40 functions from all textures from Brodatz album?

Answer (score 1):

PCA reduce the dimension of data,ICA extracts the components of the data of which dimension must <=
data dimension